# How to connect a yamaha pss 570 to audio interface

Tags: recording

I need help connecting a yamaha pss 570 to a audio interface can't seem to work it out as it dosent have any xlr ports on it ? Any help on this would be appreciated just want to record the internal sounds of the synth

Answer (score 0):

Use the jacks, XLR would be more for a mic input than instrument & unless it has a pad, would be far too sensitive.

From the manual...

[image]

Without knowing what interface you have, there's not a lot more can be said.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your keyboard has either stereo RCA jacks or Stereo quarter inch jacks, I'm not quite sure. However, the solution for both should be the same. If your interface has quarter inch inputs on it and the keyboard is quarter inch, then you just need two quarter inch to quarter inch cables. I assume, however, that you're asking because it isn't that simple. Because I don't know what interface you have, I will give two cases on what you could do based on your interface.

1) The interface has quarter inch inputs:
     This case is pretty simple. You take the RCA outs on the back of the keyboard, and grab two little RCA to Quarter inch adapters to put on the end of your stereo RCA cable. When you plug in the quarter inch cables, there should probably be a switch to choose mic/line or guitar level sound. This should be set to guitar or instrument level, whichever it is labeled as.

2) The interface only has XLR inputs:
     Either RCA or quarter inch out of the back of the keyboard. If RCA, then get the aforementioned adapters in order to change the RCA to quarter inch. Then, you will require either a stereo DI box or two mono DI boxes. This will take the quarter inch instrument level sound and change it to XLR line level, allowing you to take an XLR from the DI(s) into your interface.

Hope this helps!